# Custom date RangeAttribute will return exception on negative values for year,month and day

Tags: c#, exception, range, customvalidator, validationattribute

I created a custom DateRange attribute to check for maximum and minimum value for date. this is the code

```
 public class DateRangeAttribute : RangeAttribute
    {
        public DateRangeAttribute(int minimumYear, int minimumMonth, int minimumDay, int maximumYear, int maximumMonth, int maximumDay)
            : base(typeof(DateTime), GetMinimumDate(minimumYear, minimumMonth, minimumDay).ToShortDateString()
                , GetMaximumDate(maximumYear, maximumMonth, maximumDay).ToShortDateString())
        {
        }

        private static DateTime GetMinimumDate(int minimumYear, int minimumMonth, int minimumDay)
        {
            if (minimumDay < 0 || minimumMonth < 0 || minimumYear < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException( "the values for minimum date can not be negative." ,paramName: nameof(minimumMonth));

            }
            minimumYear = minimumYear == 0 ? DateTime.MinValue.Year : minimumYear;
            minimumMonth = minimumMonth == 0 ? DateTime.MinValue.Month : minimumMonth;
            minimumDay = minimumDay == 0 ? DateTime.MinValue.Day : minimumDay;
            return new DateTime(minimumYear, minimumMonth, minimumDay);
        }

        private static DateTime GetMaximumDate(int maximumYear, int maximumMonth, int maximumDay)
        {
            maximumYear = maximumYear == 0 ? DateTime.MaxValue.Year : maximumYear;
            maximumMonth = maximumMonth == 0 ? DateTime.MaxValue.Month : maximumMonth;
            maximumDay = maximumDay == 0 ? new DateTime(maximumYear, maximumMonth, 31) == DateTime.MaxValue.Date ?
                                           DateTime.MaxValue.Day : new DateTime(maximumYear, maximumMonth, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1).Day : maximumDay;

            return new DateTime(maximumYear, maximumMonth, maximumDay);
        }
   }
```

the code works fine almost.but in cases I pass the negative values for Year/Month/Day , it crashes in constructors. I was thinking of having a value check in constructors which can throw an exception when the parameter is negative. something like this

```
 private static DateTime GetMinimumDate(int minimumYear, int minimumMonth, int minimumDay)
  {
 if (minimumDay < 0 || minimumMonth < 0 || minimumYear < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException( "the values for minimum date can not be negative." ,paramName: nameof(minimumMonth));

            }
         // The rest of the code...
   }
```

but it doesn't work.

Update : this is how I use this attribute

```
  [DateRange(1900, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0)]
  public DateTime? OriginalDocumentDate { get; set; }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: let me who how you are using attribute

Comment: `but it doesn't work.` Please be more details about **how** it doesn't work.

Comment: one mroe thing, [DateRange(1900, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0)] when you do that you are passing intializing your RangeAttribute with that values means you are going to use this value to comparision with you inputted value , this value get compare with the datetime value you passe to property....updated my answer with that

Answer (score 0):

one mroe thing,     `[DateRange(1900, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0)]` when you do that you are passing intializing your RangeAttribute with that values means you are going to use this value to comparision with you inputted value , this value get compare with the datetime value you passe to property.

---

tried you example like this

```
public class Employee
{
    [DateRange(1900, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0)]
    public DateTime? OriginalDocumentDate { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Employee e = new Employee() { OriginalDocumentDate= DateTime.Now };
        List<ValidationResult> validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
        var vc = new ValidationContext(e, null, null);
        var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject
                (e, vc, validationResults, true);
    }
}
```

and found out there is no constructor get called when  `Validator.TryValidateObject`, this means that this attribute only take care of the methods ...i.e. when validation take place it only calls methods of validation attribute not constructor of it

---

i think you have to put this code

```
 if (minimumDay < 0 || minimumMonth < 0 || minimumYear < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException( "the values for minimum date can not be negative." ,paramName: nameof(minimumMonth));

            }
```

in you method call , because attribute constructor get called , before you set value, i.e. when you class got created before setting value ...

to try out put break point in you constructor...

---

in below code

```
class MyCustomAttribute : Attribute {
    public int[] Values { get; set; }

    public MyCustomAttribute(int[] values) {
        this.Values = values;
    }
}

[MyCustomAttribute(new int[] { 3, 4, 5 })]
class MyClass { }
```

custom attribute constructor get called with value of array [3,4,5] , and as value get passed in attribute initialization it self

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've updated the code. Whaqt do u mean by method call?? its validation attribute

Comment: @SaraN - tried your code and updated answer for the same